# Angular2 RC6 upgrade

Tags: angular, angular2-upgrade

after updating my project to `RC6` following errors occurs:

```
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  app.component.ts (12, 3): Argument of type '{ moduleId: string; selector: string; templateUrl: string; styleUrls: string[]; directives: (type...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentMetadataType'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'ComponentMetadataType'.
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NavbarComponent} from "./shared/navbar/navbar.component";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "@angular/router";
import {SidebarComponent} from "./shared/sidebar/sidebar.component";
import {FooterComponent} from "./shared/footer/footer.component";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [NavbarComponent, SidebarComponent, FooterComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): any {
    return undefined;
  }

}
```

It take my a while, but I cant figure it out.

Comment: app.component.ts code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Directives` and `pipes` must be defined in `@NgModule` If I'm reading correctly. Support inside `@Component` is removed.

So yeah just move your directives into the NgModule

At the moment you have : Component A with directives Ac and Component B with directives Bc and most likely one AppModule, you just have to move Ac and Bc into the AppModule. And yes, you have to remove them from the `@Component` declaration

The directives will then be immediately available in the components that are defined in your module.

---

Example from OP becomes:

app.component.ts

```
// imports...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

app.module.ts

```
// imports...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent, 
    SidebarComponent, 
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
               //MyService, MyOtherService
             ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**See the doc for router**: [router documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: Is that mean that I have to remove directives from all components and move it to app module or I have to change module for every single component?

Comment: You can move everything to app.module first. Later you can reorganize your app to separate components/pipes into different modules

Comment: Correct, this thing have been mentioned in change log

Comment: @ulou At the moment you have : Component A with directives Ac and Component B with directives Bc and most likely one AppModule, you just have to move Ac and Bc into the AppModule :). Edited my annswer, you might want to accept it if it helped, thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example of how this should look like!

Answer (score 5):

`directives` and `pipes` have to be defined in your `@NgModule` declarations since RC6.
Remove them from your `@Component` decorator.

Comment: Is that mean that I have to remove directives from all components and move it to app module or I have to create module for every single component?

Comment: yep, they go into the `declarations` section of your `@NgModule` now. Iif you only have the main app module it goes there.

Comment: Ok, but If I have more than 1 component, is that mean I have to create module for component A and B or just import directives to component A and somehow link it in component B?

Comment: you put it in the module declaration and it just works anywhere in the module

Comment: Makes alot of sense to me. Always wondered why this wasn't there since the start.

Comment: @Sandrooco Encapsulation maybe ? Idk

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 2 final version 2.0.0.0

the pipe should be declared in declaration section of app.module.ts file

```
import {KeysPipe} from './keys.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, LoginComponent,ArticleComponent,**KeysPipe** ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent, LoginComponent,ArticleComponent ],


})
```

just observe keyspipe implementation in above code snippets.