# Angular 2 Responsive Header - Expand/toggle button not working in mobile view

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive-design, responsive

The toggle button appears in mobile view but it's not clickable.  In angular `appDropdown` is used to define a drop down button.  Is there a similar approach to fix the toggle button?

Unfortunately I cannot show images here but there's another problem with "Administration" drop down button. It  changes colour to grey when I hover over the internal `<li>` (such as "Registration"...).

Adding `href= "#"` removes the unwanted color change but this refreshes the whole page when its clicked.

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-webmaster">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" appDropdown class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']">Title</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Sublime<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown" appDropdown *ngIf="userService.isAdmin">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administration <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/register']">Registration</a></li>
        <li><a>Other Admin  Stuff</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a>Another Admin Stuff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right search-form" role="search">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
nav.navbar-webmaster {
  background: #00547E;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav.navbar-brand :hover {
  color: #337ab7;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster ul.navbar-nav a:hover,
nav.navbar-webmaster ul.navbar-nav a:visited,
nav.navbar-webmaster ul.navbar-nav a:focus,
nav.navbar-webmaster ul.navbar-nav a:active {
  background: #0d3a51;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster ul.navbar-nav a:hover {
  border-color: #337ab7;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster li.divider {
  background: #ccc;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster button.navbar-toggle {
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster button.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: #999;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster button.navbar-toggle>span.icon-bar {
  background: #fff;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster ul.dropdown-menu {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster ul.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #444;
}

nav.navbar-webmaster ul.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  background: #00547E;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Implemented by using ng-bootstrap. Update html as below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

> Declare below variable in component class

```
public isCollapsed = false;
```

For live action, visit my [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Yrtwx02y70qJ91ZvInjB/)

Comment: Thank you.  It's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I've tried this, but I get "Can't bind to 'ngbCollapse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'."

Comment: @BBaysinger , you need to follow instructions in valor-software.com//#/dropdowns which prompts you to import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap'; and even @NgModule({
  imports: [CollapseModule.forRoot(),...]          Beyond that - you ought to use [collapse]="isCollapsed" instead of [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed"

Comment: It works. But now I have a new issue. What would be needed to make the navbar collapse again once a nav item has been clicked. If you click on a nav item and a new component/page is loaded in the SPA, the navbar remains expanded.